# Cannot reach Pi via ethernet after disabling wireless interface

Tags: networking, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, route, systemd-networkd

I have a raspberry pi running Arch Linux ARM connected on two interfaces. It uses systemd-networkd.

- `eth0` is connected on a DMZ. It has a static ip and it's behind a router with a public ip and port forwarding.
- `wlan0` is connected on a wifi network (LAN). It has a local ip.

I can ssh into the pi through both the public ip and the local ip. There is a webserver running on the pi, and I can access ip via the public ip.

However, for security reasons, I now want to prevent the pi to connect to the local network. But whenever I disconnect from the wifi, I lose all connectivity to the pi on the public ip (and local ip as well as expected).

This is the command I tried to disconnect from the wifi:

```
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service

ip link set wlan0
```

I would like to find out why shutting down the wlan0 interface would also block any connection on a public ip that is supposed to be routed through the eth0 interface. There is probably a routing problem and I would be glad if you could help pinpoint it.

Please the result of a few commands that might be of interest:

```
$ ip route show
default via 172.16.16.16 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 172.16.16.25 metric 1024 
10.0.0.0/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 
172.16.16.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.16.25 
172.16.16.16 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 172.16.16.25 metric 1024 

$ ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:1c:2b:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.2/29 brd 10.0.0.7 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe1c:2bb1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:1c:2b:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.16.25/24 brd 172.16.16.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 80544sec preferred_lft 80544sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe1c:2bb2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
....
.... other docker related interface
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the route to the gateway.

`ip route add default via gateway_ip dev eth0` solved my problem.